# How to to log visitor info in sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

How to add a record for each page visit in sails.js. Very similar to what general web analytics do, I assume this is some js code in the template, but I'd like to add this data to own database for logging.

Data should contain: date/time, user (if applicable), geolocation and the page.

Perhaps there is an existing sails machine or script out there?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Reword your question as your current question is asking for an opinionated answer. i.e. *best way...*

Comment: Done. Hope this is better.

Comment: What problem are you having? Identifying page load events? Getting the current date and time? Identifying the user? Performing geolocation? Identifying the page? Inserting data into a database? Designing the database table?

Comment: "Perhaps there is an existing sails machine or script out there?" — Shopping questions are off-topic for SO.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the best practice in logging some basic data from a visitor for each page visit in sails.js. Basic, that is, it would also require geolocation coming from the web browser. This data should be added to a model with pagestats, whenever the page is loaded.

I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction, or some sample code that could do just this. Perhaps there is something already built-in sails?